# read from secondary with mgo.Monotonic

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, martini

I am trying to configure reading from primary and two secondary nodes of mongo replica set to provide better load balancing. Each of 3 nodes are on different machines with IP addresses: ip1, ip2, ip3.

My `GoLang` site, which is the `martini` web server with two urls `/insert` and `/get`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    dialStr        = "ip1:port1,ip2:port2,ip3:port3"
    dbName         = "test"
    collectionName = "test"
    elementsCount  = 1000
)

var mainSessionForSave *mgo.Session

func ConnectToMongo() {
    var err error
    mainSessionForSave, err = mgo.Dial(dialStr)
    mainSessionForSave.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func GetMgoSessionPerRequest() *mgo.Session {
    var sessionPerRequest *mgo.Session
    sessionPerRequest = mainSessionForSave.Copy()
    return sessionPerRequest
}

func main() {
    ConnectToMongo()
    prepareMartini().Run()
}

type Element struct {
    I int `bson:"I"`
}

func prepareMartini() *martini.ClassicMartini {
    m := martini.Classic()
    sessionPerRequest := GetMgoSessionPerRequest()
    m.Get("/insert", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        for i := 0; i < elementsCount; i++ {
            e := Element{I: i}
            err := collection(sessionPerRequest).Insert(&e)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
        w.Write([]byte("data inserted successfully"))
    })
    m.Get("/get", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var element Element
        const findI = 500
        err := collection(sessionPerRequest).Find(bson.M{"I": findI}).One(&element)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        w.Write([]byte("get data successfully"))

    })

    return m
}

func collection(s *mgo.Session) *mgo.Collection {
    return s.DB(dbName).C(collectionName)
}
```

I run this `GoLang` site with the command `go run site.go` and to prepare my experiment requested `http://localhost:3000/insert` - after about a minute my test data was inserted.

Then I started to test reading from secondary and primary nodes
in `attacker.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    vegeta "github.com/tsenart/vegeta/lib"
)

func main() {

    rate := uint64(4000) // per second
    duration := 4 * time.Second
    targeter := vegeta.NewStaticTargeter(&vegeta.Target{
        Method: "GET",
        URL:    "http://localhost:3000/get",
    })
    attacker := vegeta.NewAttacker()

    var results vegeta.Results
    for res := range attacker.Attack(targeter, rate, duration) {
        results = append(results, res)
    }

    metrics := vegeta.NewMetrics(results)
    fmt.Printf("99th percentile: %s\n", metrics.Latencies.P99)
}
```

Running it `go run attacker.go` I just requested URL `http://localhost:3000/get` **4000** times per second. While attacker was working I opened all my 3 servers and run `htop` command to watch resources consumption. The PRIMARY node shows that it is under high load with CPU about 80%. The SECONDARIES were calm.

### Why?

As I used `mgo.Monotonic` ...

```
mainSessionForSave.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
```

... I expected to read from all nodes: `ip1, ip2, ip3` and I expected to watch all the nodes under equal load and  with equal CPU consumption. But it is not so. What did I configure wrong? In fact `mgo.Monotonic` is not working in my case and I read only from the **PRIMARY** node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sessionPerRequest` is only created once: `prepareMartini` is called at server startup, and `sessionPerRequest` is set then. The closures passed to `m.Get()` access that variable. Then, after the first write (during your test setup), [`mgo` will only access the primary](https://labix.org/mgo):

> Monotonic consistency will start reading from a slave if possible, so that the load is better distributed, and *once the first write happens the connection is switched to the master*.

(If `mgo` just continued reading from the secondary after writing to the primary, a read wouldn't necessarily reflect a write you just made, which could be a pain. And switching to the primary should only get you *newer* data than you were getting from the secondary, never older, which preserves monotonicity. That's how it should ideally work, anyway; see the "open issues" link below for more.)

The solution is to push creating the session down into your handlers, e.g., remove `sessionPerRequest` and put something explicit atop each handler, like

```
coll := mainSessionForSave.Copy().DB(dbName).Collection(collName)
```

All consistency promises should be read in light of [open issues with MongoDB consistency](https://aphyr.com/posts/322-call-me-maybe-mongodb-stale-reads): right now, during network partitions, reads can see old data and writes that will later be rolled back, even when `mgo` is trying to read from the primary. (Compare-and-set doesn't have this issue, but of course that's a larger slower operation.) It's also worth perusing that post just for the discussion of the consistency levels and the descriptions of how different database behaviors might manifest for an app's end-users.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close connections after use it:

```
defer mainSessionForSave.Close()
```

Probably, it may be a reason.

P.S. make sure that all your nodes is available :)

Comment: I use this connection for every request: `sessionPerRequest = mainSessionForSave.Copy()`, so I don't need to close it before all site will be terminated. All nodes are available.